Prove that in an 8-element subset of $\{1,2, \dots 15 \}$ there must exist three 2-element subsets whose difference is the same number
I managed to prove that there must exist 2 pairs (pairs here is 2-element subsets) whose difference is the same. Here is my reasoning:
We have 14 total unique differences ${1, 2, \dots 14}$ so there are $14$ holes for our pigeons, where the pigeons here are all the possible pairs of the 8-element subset, that is, we have $\binom 8 2 =28$ pigeons. So, by pigeonhole principle there have to be at least $2$ pairs of those $28$ whose difference are the same. I have no idea how to prove that there are in fact 3 pairs with the same difference.  Also, I figured there is $\frac{14(14+1)}{2}=105$ not necessarily unique differences in total, I didn't see how this could help, but perhaps it can?
example: for $\{2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 15\}$ we have $15-13=13-11=8-6=2$
thanks

@peterwhy thanks, I just got around understanding that answer as well, that's it. thanks
